# How to wake up/start not running app from c2dm listener on Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-c2dm

i am running into issues during testing when my app is not running in the background. I broadcast c2dm message to it, it does received it, i the service performs AsyncTask to grab some data off my server, all is good until it fails on "onPostExecute" with a MessageQueue error:

> sending message to a Handler on a dead
>   thread

everything works fine when the app is running in the background, but fails when it's not. do i have to wake it up somehow? thanks!

**UPDATE:** here is the snippet of my AsyncTask:

```
private class getNewMessages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private Context gContext;
    private String gToken;
    private int gNewMessages;

    public getNewMessages(Context context, String token) {
        super();
        gContext = context;
        gToken = token;
    }  
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... args) {
        gNewMessages = data.serverNewMessagesGet(gContext, gToken);
        return true;
    }   
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Log.d(common.DEBUG_TAG, "retrieved " + gNewMessages + " new messages");     
        // notify user, etc...
    }       
 }
```

**UPDATE #2:** Error stack trace

```
Handler{4585c038} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{4585c038} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:184)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:367)
at android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:348)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:214)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSet(FutureTask.java:252)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.set(FutureTask.java:112)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: If there's an exception, can you post a stack trace?

Comment: @Roman Nurik: stack trace included. i just read something saying that AsyncTask should only be used from the UI Thread. Don't know if this is true or not.

Comment: Yeah, `onPostExecute` is called on the calling thread, which must be alive, and which must have a `Looper` ... I'm not sure if `AsyncTask` must be called from the UI thread, but that does make sense. If you're running this code from an `IntentService`, not that you're already in a non-UI thread.

Comment: i removed the AsyncTask and it works fine when the app is not running. wondering if i really need this in the service... i just don't want the app to freeze when it gets the data. will it? when it's executed from inside the service?

Comment: You can just spawn a separate thread without using an AsyncTask. IntentService spawns a thread for you; plain vanilla services run in the main thread so be careful with that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you firing up an `AsyncTask` from within a broadcast receiver? If so, you'll likely want to move your `AsyncTask` to a service, and start the service from the receiver. Broadcast receivers aren't intended to be used for much more than very basic book-keeping or just starting a service or activity.

**EDIT**: Also consider using the very handy [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class, which handles its intent in a separate thread and stops itself when it's done.

Comment: i am running the AsycTask from the service, my receiver does start the service.

Comment: Ah ok, just saw that note. Can you update your question with a code snippet for the AsyncTask?